# How can I use Express Session in my http server?

Tags: typescript, express, express-session

Hello I want to store my users information inside Express session and we are still in development and we are using a vps to share the express server. My problem is that when I log the session it will return undefined but if I use my host which is https, it would work fine. What should I do to use it in http url?

Index.ts:

```
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import session from 'express-session';
import compression from 'compression';
import cors from 'cors';
import path from 'path';
import { existsSync, mkdirSync } from 'fs';
import logger from 'morgan';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import schema from './schema';
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from 'graphql-upload';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Session {
      dashboardData: any;
    }
  }
}

const app = express();
const server = new ApolloServer({
  uploads: false,
  schema,
  playground: true,
  context: ({ req, res }) => {
    const auth = req.headers.authorization || '';
    return {
      auth,
      session: req.session,
    }
  }
});

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  credentials: true,
}));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://localhost:3000');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(compression());
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secretabcd',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  name: 'someName',
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    sameSite: true,
  }
}));

app.use(graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 1000000000, maxFiles: 10 }));

existsSync(path.join(__dirname, "../files")) || mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "../files"));
existsSync(path.join(__dirname, "../templates")) || mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "../templates"));

app.use("/files", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../files")));
app.use("/templates", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../templates")));

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql', cors: false });

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is ready at port 4000`);
});
```

Comment: What happens if you use the cors module?

Comment: What do you mean to use cors?

Comment: check this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: I am using Cors in my code